# Can SystemJS plugins modify already transpiled files?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jspm, systemjs, ng-annotate

While attempting to get Angular (1.x) working with systemjs I realized that there is not currently the capability (that I know of) to automatically insert `$inject` into angular components, which keeps the components working even when the arguments to the functions are mangled by the minifier.  Manually creating the `$inject` annotations is tedious, error-prone and violates the *DRY* principal.

There is a mature npm module called `ng-annotate` which solves this problem and is used in many similar situations for bundling.  As I've been exploring SystemJS, I see that there is a plugin system that includes the ability to translate source code, which is exactly what `ng-annotate` does.

From what I can see, though, SystemJS only gives you the ability to map a particular file extension to a single loader and all the examples of the plugins are to support a new file type.  What I would like to do is post-process the output of SystemJS's transpilation process rather than add a new file type.  It seems like SystemJS should be able to do this since it has a processing pipeline, but I can't quite figure out how to hook into it the right way.  Right now I am using Browserify to achieve the same effect, but I have ended up with a rather complex set of build tasks and I would like to simplify it with SystemJS if possible.

Other strategies to be able to use `ng-annotate` in the loader pipeline with SystemJS would be appreciated too.

Comment: Why don't you use inline array annotation?

Comment: Because the style of code that I'm writing is not conducive to it.  I'm writing in Typescript where most of my services end up as classes and I register my services with the module in a separate file, not in the same file as the service.  Also, as with `$inject` it violates *DRY*.  Finally, angular is not the primary topic of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I figured out a way, but this feels really clunky.  `System.src` itself uses a `hook()` function to do this, but it's not exported for use.  I'd be grateful for any ways to improve this and I hope eventually a properly supported mechanism for chaining loader functionality becomes available:

```js
var System = require('systemjs');
var systemTranslate = System.translate;
System.translate = function(load) {
  return systemTranslate.call(this, load).then(function (result) {
    if (result) {
      var processedResult = result; // Do your processing here.
      load.source = processedResult;
    }
    return load.source;
  });
}
```

I haven't experimented much with this, since my particular use cases for System.js building is currently a dead-end (Typescript source-maps are still busted), but presumably you can also return a promise.

I'll leave this answer un-chosen for a while to see if anybody has some better advice.